# Is it possible to change focusing level on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am using the following code to display the address search bar when Find Postcode button is clicked.

```
  function openDaumPostcode() {
   
var element_wrap = document.getElementById('wrap');
if(jQuery("#wrap").css("display") == "none") {

            new daum.Postcode({
                oncomplete: function(data) {
                    document.getElementById('billing_postcode').value = data.zonecode;
                    document.getElementById('billing_address_1').value = data.address;
                    document.getElementById('billing_address_2').focus();
},

onresize : function(size) {
                element_wrap.style.height = size.height+'px';
            },
            width : '100%',
            height : '100%',
        
onclose:function(state) {
                    if(state === "COMPLETE_CLOSE") {

                        // Execute the callback function to proceed with the slide-up function after execution is completed.
                        offDaumZipAddress2(function() {
                            element_wrap.style.display = "none";
                        });
                    }
                }
            }).embed(element_wrap);
jQuery("#wrap").slideDown();
        }

else {

            // Execute the callback function to proceed with the slide-up function after execution is completed.
            offDaumZipAddress2(function() {
                element_wrap.style.display = "none";
                return false;
            });
        }
      }
    function offDaumZipAddress2() {
        // Close the layer window using the slide-up function.
        jQuery("#wrap").slideUp();

    }
```

And using the code below, I made a Warp element to specify where the address search bar should appear.

```
    const parent = document.querySelector('#billing_postcode_find_field');
    const billingField1 = document.querySelector('#woocommerce-input-wrapper');

    const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.setAttribute('id', 'wrap');
   newDiv.style.cssText = 'display:none;width:100%;margin:5px 0;position:relative';

       parent.insertBefore(newDiv, billingField1);
```

And the structure of my website is as below.

```
<div class="woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper">
    <p class="billing_postcode_find_field">..
        <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">...
        </span>
      </p>
  
    <div id="wrap" ..> </div>
   
   <p class="billing_address_1_field">
         <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
```

This method usually works well. But the problem is the ".focus" that went into the code below.

```
document.getElementById('shipping_address_2').focus();
```

When i select an address in the address search bar, it is automatically entered into billing_address_1.

Then the focus is on the billing_address_2 field.

However, as the billing_address_2 field is focused so that it is located at the top, the scroll goes down to the end.

Is there any way to adjust this focusing level?

My English is not good, so I made a gif and [linked it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kkV5.jpg).

I'd like to hear advice.

Thank you

Comment: There is no way to prevent the browser from scrolling when you change the input focus.

Comment: Hard to tell exactly what's happening - it *looks like* the .focus() is forcing the page to scroll so that element is in focus, but is scrolling it to the top.  Instead, if you manually scroll the page so that the input is fully visible on the page first, then when you give it focus (after it has scrolled), the browser won't need to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `.focus()` on an element, the browser forces that element into view (so the user can see where they're entering values).

If the element is not in the view, the browser will scroll.  How it does this depends on the browser - in your case, it scrolls the input to the top of the page.

If the element is already in view, the browser will not scroll.   So the solution is to ensure the element is already in view before you call .focus().

One option is to use [`.scrollIntoView(false)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).

Here's an example, showing the difference:

```js
$("#b1").click(() => {
    document.getElementById("in2").focus();
});

$("#b2").click(() => {
    document.getElementById("in2").scrollIntoView(false);
    document.getElementById("in2").focus();
});
```

```css
div { height:120vh; border: 1px dashed #CCC; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
INPUT 1: <input id='in1' type='text'>
<button id='b1'>focus</button>
<button id='b2'>scroll + focus</button>
<div></div>
INPUT 2: <input id='in2' type='text'>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Also [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/60h7oLeg/)